# Filter Out an Object with the Exception Property

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I am currently executing a series of HTTP requests, synchronously, in a loop and then saving the result of each one in its respective index.

If the HTTP request is a `200` I should receive back a model that looks something similar to:

```
{
    Item: { ... },
    Removed: true
}
```

However, there is a potential for an item to fail and throw an `HttpResponseException` in which case my model comes back as:

```
{
    Exception: {ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo},
    Item: { ... },
    Removed: true
}
```

The calling code looks like:

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    var exception = new HttpResponseException("ExceptionThrown!");
    throw exception;
}
```

Firstly, why does C# add the `Exception` property to my model?

Secondly, if I want to filter all of the results based on results which did *not* throw exceptions, how would I achieve that? I've been trying to do:

```
return results
    .Where(result => result != null)
    .Select(result => new MyModel
    {
        One: result.Item,
        Two: result.Removed
    })
    .ToList();
```

But I receive the items with the `Exception` property. Thoughts?

Comment: "C#" doesn't add anything; that comes from whatever code produced the model.  Which you haven't told us anything about.

Comment: This is how your Server side code would be written. If you want something else then handle it in friendly way at your server application. Default for error would be from System.Web.Http for different responses. There will always in result/response either as success or failure code. Check if response.StatusCode is 200 in where condition for filtering